# Neo4j copied database files without permissions and now can't use them

Tags: neo4j

I have a Neo4J database (Version: 3.3.1) running on Ubuntu 16.04.

I backed up the database files by copying and pasting the folder that contains them.

I then screwed up the original database and went to restore the backup by deleting the screwed up one and copying the backup to the same location as the original one.

Running the DB fails and I can only think that this is because the original "databases" and "dbms" folders belong to permissions group "neo4j".  The copies I made don't carry these permissions because I stupidly copied the folder with a copy paste rather than using "sudo cp -rp" which would have carried their permissions and therefore worked (I tested that).

I tried "chown :neo4j databases" and "chown :neo4j dbms" to change the group for these folders to "neo4j" as per the original but it didn't work.

I don't seem to get an error in the error log at "/var/log/neo4j/debug.log" either.

Any idea what I need to do to my backup folder to get it working please?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Have you tried navigating to folder and trying to give it a 777 permission ? 
`chmod -R 777 .`  ?
Can you post the **error message** that you get?

Comment: Yes, chown -R neo4j. databases would be a better idea. Make the owner and group neo4j. Also, java exceptions, at least early in the startup cycle, often appear in /var/log/messages, so see if there's something there that gives a further clue.

Comment: Thanks. You got it.  I checked the permissions on the original database folders and they were `drwxr-xr-x` with user `neo4j` and group `neo4j`.  So I have just updated the backup database to have these permissions etc and it all works perfectly.  Thanks very much!